# Segue is not working, and i can't figure out why

Tags: ios, segue, swift3, xcode8

I have an if...then statement in the ViewDidLoad method for the view that acts as my storyboard entry point.

Basically, I am doing a check to see if there is any data in core data, to indicate that they've completed a small "setup form".

If it is found that the core data is empty or that the app has not been properly set up, I want it to automatically kick them over to the settings view with a segue.

My ViewDidLoad method looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Get any entries from the App Settings Entity
    getAppSettings()


    //If any entries are found, check to see if the setup has been completed
    if (appSettings.count > 0) {

        print("We found entries in the database for App Settings")

        if (appSettings[0].setupComplete == false) {
            print("Setup has not been completed")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAppSettings", sender: self)
        } else {
            print("Setup is completed")
            //Load the settings into global variables
            preferredRegion = appSettings[0].region!
            usersName = appSettings[0].usersName!
        }

    } else { 
        print("We found no entries in the database for App Settings")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toAppSettings", sender: self)
    }
}
```

I made sure that the segue does exist, and that the identifier for the segue is exactly as I have it in the quotes (I even copied & pasted all instances of it to make sure that they are all consistent).

I also went the extra mile and put a checker in the "prepare for segue" method, to print whether it was getting called, and who the sender was:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("We're getting ready to segue!")
    print(segue.identifier)
}
```

Both of those items get printed to the log, which tells me that the segue is being recognized and that the app is attempting to fire it. But - for some reason that I can't figure out - it simply isn't firing.

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an if...then statement in the ViewDidLoad

But that's the problem. `viewDidLoad` is way too early for this. Remember, all `viewDidLoad` means is that your view controller has a view. That's all it means. That view is not yet in the interface, and the view controller itself may not even be in the view hierarchy! It's just sitting out there in object space. You cannot segue from here; there is nothing to segue from.

Try waiting until `viewDidAppear`. If that makes it work, you might try moving it back to `viewWillAppear`, but I don't guarantee anything. Keep in mind that these methods can be called multiple times, so you might also need a flag to make sure that this segue fires just the once.